# How to solve Build Error:unhandled LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS "APPS"?

Tags: android, build, android-source

I want to add my pre-built APK to my AOSP build. I've created the following folders *vendor/aaa/crespo* and pasted my APK inside the folder. I've also created a make file to install my APK.

The make file is as follows:

```
$(call inherit-product, $(SRC_TARGET_DIR)/product/generic.mk)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := vendor/aaa/crespo/
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(strip $(LOCAL_MODULE_PATH))
ifeq ($(LOCAL_MODULE_PATH),)
  LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $($(my_prefix)OUT$(partition_tag)_$(LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS))
  ifeq ($(strip $(LOCAL_MODULE_PATH)),)
    $(error $(LOCAL_PATH): unhandled LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS "$(LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS)")
  endif
endif
  # Module name should match apk name to be installed.
  LOCAL_MODULE := test
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
  LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
  LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
  LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
  LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
  include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the make file? In this make file, I want to tell the compiler to add my APK into the build. It builds fine but my app is not present in the *installed-files.txt* file.

Comment: You don't need to process LOCAL_MODULE_PATH like that, build system will already do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading build script at [github](https://github.com/android/platform_build/blob/master/core/base_rules.mk#L113)

```
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(strip $(LOCAL_MODULE_PATH))
ifeq ($(LOCAL_MODULE_PATH),)
  LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $($(my_prefix)OUT$(partition_tag)_$(LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS))
  ifeq ($(strip $(LOCAL_MODULE_PATH)),)
    $(error $(LOCAL_PATH): unhandled LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS "$(LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS)")
  endif
endif
```

It is your path that's wrong. If Android.mk is at the same directory, I don't think you need to put path in front of it. By the way you are also not setting LOCAL_CERTIFICATE - I don't know if necessary but majority seems to set it.

Comment: then in which directory should my apk be kept??

Comment: you should describe your directory structure & file names in a case sensitive way.

Comment: yep! took care about case sensitivity and also i've kept the apk in same directory *vendor/aaa/crespo/test.apk* . Is it ok then?

Comment: PLz check now! i've updated the make file still ma app is not present in the installed-files.txt after build

Comment: You need to have it in PRODUCT_PACKAGES. Btw next time you start a build just type 'mm' in that directory you may get a shorter build.

Comment: PRODUCT_PACKAGES?? i'm new to make files? plz provide steps for it!!

Comment: Sorry, you should some how better define your questions. This one may go on forever. (for PRODUCT_PACKAGES search on Google)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it helped to include `Android.mk` with definitions via macro `all-makefiles-under`:

```
include $(call all-makefiles-under, $(LOCAL_PATH))
```

Problem occurred when i include Android.mk directly.